# Routing Error in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two button in my index page

1. Register
2. Login

If I clicked I should redirect to `new.html.erb` page, but when I clicked in register button I found the below error. please help me to resolve this error.

**Error:**

```
No route matches [POST] "/posts/new"
```

My code snippets are given below.

In **posts/index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Index page</h1>
<h1>Register Here</h1>
<hr />
<p>
<%= button_to "REGISTER",posts_new_path%>
</p>
<p>
<%= button_to "LOGIN" %>
</p>
```

In **posts/new.html.erb**

```
<h1>Register Here</h1>
```

In **controller/posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

    def new
       @user=User.new
    end
end
```

In **config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   root "posts#index"
   get "posts/new" => "posts#new"
  #resources:posts
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # root 'welcome#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

I am using rails version-4

Comment: Check the o/p of rake routes and you will find the available generated routes for new posts. Button_to generates a form which is for submitting data with post request. Check the method type in views and routes

Answer (score 3):

`posts_new_path` isn't defined anywhere in your application.

I'd suggest you take a look at the [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to gain a deeper understanding but the quickest way to fix this is to change your routes.rb file to read:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "posts#index"
  get "posts/new" => "posts#new", as: new_post
  #resources:posts
end
```

And in your view:

```
<%= button_to "REGISTER",new_post_path%>
```

Using the `as` method in the routes creates a named route using the phrase specified with either `path` or `url` on the end, which can then be used in your views.

You could use the phrase `resources :posts` which would expose a number of named routes in your application for the 7 CRUD actions. Read up in the guide on this as it may be good for you depending on how your application is structured.

Answer (score 1):

The default method for `button_to` is `:post`, you need to call it with method get option:

```
<%= button_to "REGISTER", posts_new_path, method: :get %>
```

Refer to http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to